# When upgrading non official repository (ppa) will be lost?

Tags: upgrade, ppa

Actually I want to upgrade to the newly released Ubuntu **14.04** from a saucy **13.10** version. Regarding that I never run into an upgrade process from a *nix version to an onward one, I want your kind rectification on what files will be changed in this upgrade process:

- Does non official repository (ppa) will be lost?
- If some sources modified, will they be backed up to original state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-official repos are disabled during upgrade.

I am not sure about your second point. Which sources are you referring to? Is it the ppa sources? Yes they are backed up but disabled.

After the upgrade is complete, you can check the status of those ppas from "Software Sources", and re-enable them. I guess you will need to purge gnome3 ppas if you are using them before you upgrade.

You can use a tool called y ppa manager, which you might find helpful to enable/disable individual ppas (ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying those points, and what about personal data and session files (_.profile_ ,_.bashrc_...) No need to care?

Comment: The upgrade process attempts to keep installed applications whenever it can. I would say that .bashrc and _profile files should also persist.

Comment: `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` are preserved; nothing in the homes will be touched (although some applications, when you upgrade them, update the format of their config files when first run).  However,`/etc/bashrc` and `/etc/profile` *will* be updated. I think that if you modified them by hand, then the upgrade system will notice and ask for confirmation (not 100% sure though; double-check if it's vital for you).

Comment: @tmarwen there isn't the term as "official PPA". PPA's are 3rd party repositories **always**. The only official are the mirrors of Ubuntu.